# My lamp was making a noise. Now it won't turn on. How to fix?

Tags: lighting, circuit-breaker, power

The lamps in my bathroom was blinking and making a hissing noise. I think the noise was coming from just one of the lamps but I'm not sure.

Now I don't have any light / power in the bathroom.

I replaced all the fuses even though I don't think any of them were broken.

I removed the light socket that I think may have caused a shirt circuit. So now I have two wires sticking out of the lamp in the ceiling.

No power in the bathroom still.

I still have light and power in the rest of my apartment.

Coild it be a short circuit in the wiring in the walls? Wouldn't that result in a broken fuse the moment I try to turn on the power?

I guess it's obvious by this post I know very little about the subject.

Any suggestions to what could be wrong and how to fix it?

Janey

Comment: I just experienced the noise (hissing / crackling) again. Now I'm thinking it might be coming from the switch box. Could this be a fire hazard? Maybe I should just get an electrician huh? ☺

Comment: An electrician seems like a really good idea; otherwise you might start an electrical fire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to troubleshoot the problem and this is best done with an electrical portable meter. You probably don't have one, a local harware store would have it. Safety first in everything you do here. If you have fuses remove it from the bathroom circuit at the main panel.
The "lamps" in the bathroom need to be tested in another location and the wiring coming into the electrical boxes need to be inspected (this includes the switch box) and I recommend a new light fixture and/or a new light switch hardwired in the bathroom. Then replace the bathroom fuse at the main panel and flip the light switch on. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes a lighbulb blowing can trip a gfci.

My guess would be that everything in the bathroom, including the lights, runs through a GFCI - somewhere there should be an outlet that has test and reset buttons.  Press the reset button and see if everything comes back on.